# Delete row if Column H contains any of the following values - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete a row if Column H contains any of the following values:

```
1) %
2) Resistor
3) Capacitor
4) MCKT
5) Connector
6) anything else I may want to add to this list...
```

Found this on Google and edited - it works well - not sure if there is a more "efficient" way to do it.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
lastrow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
readrow = 1
For n = 1 to lastrow
  If Range("H" & ReadRow).Value = "%" Or _
    Range("H" & ReadRow).Value = "Resistor" Or _
    Range("H" & ReadRow).Value = "Capacitor" Or _
    Range("H" & ReadRow).Value = "MCKT" Or _
    Range("H" & ReadRow).Value = "Connector" Then
    Range("H" & ReadRow).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
      readrow = readrow + 1
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.  What have you tried?

Comment: I would learn how to use loops if i were you

Answer (score 5):

There are more efficient methods but with this one:

1. loop backwards.
2. Change the ReadRow to n, no sense in having two variables:

code:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim Lastrow as long, n as long
lastrow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For n =  lastrow to 1 Step -1
  If Range("H" & n).Value = "%" Or _
    Range("H" & n).Value = "Resistor" Or _
    Range("H" & n).Value = "Capacitor" Or _
    Range("H" & n).Value = "MCKT" Or _
    Range("H" & n).Value = "Connector" Then
        Rows(n).Delete
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Another method is to use `Select Case`

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim Lastrow as long, n as long
lastrow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For n =  lastrow to 1 Step -1

  Select Case Range("H" & n).Value 
      Case "%","Resistor","Capacitor","MCKT","Connector"
        Rows(n).Delete
  End Select
Next
End Sub
```

It makes it easier to add to the list.

Comment: what is the purpose of Step -1? Wouldn't you want it to go from the first to last row...not the last row -1? @Scott Craner

Comment: Disregard my previous comment - I see what your doing - what is the purpose of going from the last row up versus the first row down? @Scott Craner

Comment: @CC268 when you delete a row say row 10, then what was row 11 becomes row 10 and when it iterates, n goes from 10 to 11, what was row 11 and now 10 gets skipped.  By going backwards it does not have this problem of skipping rows.

Comment: Tried both codes - neither worked - I think maybe the search criteria isn't quite correct? I just need it to delete the row if it finds those words anywhere within the cell. I don't want it to be case sensitive. For instance in some cells it may be "RESISTOR" another could be "Resistor". Maybe I will try adding an asterisk at the end and see if that helps @Scott Craner

Comment: Also it is having issues with your row(n). Delete - it states "sub or function not defined"

Comment: @CC268 fixed the `row(n)` error, forgot the `s`.  But the other would take a different code.  You will need to use `Like` or `Instr` to test.

Answer (score 0):

This worked great.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Delete_Rows()

Dim LastRow As Long, ReadRow As Long, n As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).row
End With

ReadRow = 1
For n = 1 To LastRow
  If Range("H" & ReadRow).Value Like "*%*" = True Or _
    Range("H" & ReadRow).Value Like "*Resistor*" = True Or _
    Range("H" & ReadRow).Value Like "*Transistor*" = True Or _
    Range("H" & ReadRow).Value Like "*Micro*" = True Then
      Range("H" & ReadRow).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
      ReadRow = ReadRow + 1
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```